# Urban airship set alias

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

Thanks for previous replies,

I am very new to Urban_Airship and integrating this into my android application, i really don't know what is alias for urban airship, can anyone please guide me to understand about what is alias and how to set a tag and alias in urban airship. I am really sorry if the question is not good enough, i just want to lean more on urban airship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setAlias(String)](https://docs.urbanairship.com/android-lib/reference/com/urbanairship/push/PushManager.html#setAlias%28java.lang.String%29) method with a string parameter.